# Interaction of Makefile `file` function with `rm`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've discovered the Makefile `file` function a few days ago and it's perfect for what I need to do.... except there is something I can't make sense of.

See this trivial Makefile:

```
FILENAME := test.txt
CONTENT  := whatever

all: clean
ifneq (1, $(CLEAN))
    rm -f $(FILENAME)
endif
    $(file > $(FILENAME),$(CONTENT))
    ls $(FILENAME)

clean:
ifeq (1, $(CLEAN))
    rm -f $(FILENAME)
endif
```

I've tried different version of `make`, both on Linux and Windows and I consistently get this (unexpected) behavior:

- `make CLEAN=1 all` generates a file as expected
- `make CLEAN=0 all` does not, although it's (apparently at least) going through the very same steps, just re-organized between the `clean` and the `all` targets.

Can someone explain the mystery please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(file ...)` is a make function.  `rm` is a shell command.

When make is getting ready to invoke a shell to run a recipe, it will expand all variables and functions in the recipe FIRST.  Since `$(file ...)` is a make function, it's invoked at this time.

Then after all the variables and functions are expanded, the recipe is given to the shell and the shell runs the shell commands, like `rm` etc.

So if you have an `rm` then first make creates the file due to `$(file ...)`, then your script removes it due to `rm`.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification ! Essentially you are saying that within my `all` recipe, the natural sequential order does not apply... The  [documentation of the file function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html) gives a pretty similar example though, except that `rm` and `file` appear in a different order... The example happens to work because `file` always appears (and is processed) first , but is it really a great example ?

Comment: Yes.  All make operations always happen first.  This is always true.  For example if you have a recipe `echo hi > foo.x ; $(shell cat foo.x)` it will fail because the `$(shell ...)` function is expanded before the recipe (and thus the `echo`) is run.  As for the example, it looks OK to me.  In that recipe the `rm` is expected to come last, and indeed it does.

Comment: In my `all` target, if I was replacing `rm -f $(FILENAME)` with `$(shell rm -f $(FILENAME))`, would the latter be guaranteed to be called before the `$(file ...)` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.